# Pagination numbering

Tags: php, pagination

Can anyone explain to me how I make 1 2 3 4 5 ..... 9. And when u get to 9 it shows a new row. Because at the moment it shows 900 results in a row. I just need explanation on how to get started.

Pagination script:

```
$k = 0; # The new index
$newArray = array(); # The new array
foreach($sortedImages as $soImg) {
    $newArray[$k] = $soImg;
    $k++;
}

$page = $_GET["page"];
$perPage = 10;
$total = $count;
$pages = ceil($count / $perPage);
for ($i = (($page-1)*$perPage); $i < min(($page*$perPage), $total); $i++) {
    $newSortedImages[$i] = $newArray[$i];
}
```

This is the script I use to show the numbering.

```
        page:&nbsp<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
     echo('&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the modulo operator is particularly useful for this...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
  echo('&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>');
  if ($i % 9 == 0) echo "<br />";
}
```

the modulo operator returns the remainder in a division calculation, when $i is evenly divisible by 9, it returns zero, meaning you've iterated through nine more results.

---

UPDATE:

you were close - rather than iterating all pages, just iterate 9 from the current page.

```
$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET["page"]) && is_numeric($_GET["page"])) $page = floor($_GET["page"]);
$offset = max(0, ($page + 9 - $total)); //push the start backwards if we are near the end
$start = $page - $offset;
$end = min($total, $start+9); // don't go past the total (if less then 9 items)

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
  echo('&nbsp&nbsp;<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a>');
}
```

Comment: This is the result I am getting. http://i.imgur.com/ygFcLPn.png its not quite what I mean.

Comment: It seems I cant get it to work. and I have no clue why.

Comment: can you clarify any further? are you getting an error or warning at all? Do you need to make sure $_GET["page"] is set? (i will update my code)

Comment: sorry - i also removed  the "var" definitions - working in too many languages concurrently at the moment ;)

Comment: ye I removed those myself aswell. :) but I dont get a single error message. it might be me doing it wrong sinds my php experience is really low.

Comment: I think its an issue with the echo, Because its not giving any output.

Comment: i just tried the code myself - and it seems to be working fine ... have you got access to error logs you can check ?

Comment: hmm strange can I send u the entire code. Maybe there is an issue somewhere else. the error logs doesnt say anything either.

Comment: well for a start - i don't see you echoing the page count at all in that code? also you need to incorporate the changes i made to check if $_GET["page"] exists ...

also i noticed you aren't initialising $newSortedImages anywhere - php is making up for it - but you should probably do it.

Comment: The page count echo is not in the pastebin. I am using Newsortedimages in a foreach loop but that is just lazy coding on my part.

Comment: I just realised though it only goes + and not backwards. Is that intentional?

Comment: if you wanted to center the current page and show 4 either side of it ... just adjust the $start variable accordingly (minus 4)  - note that similar to how you prevent it going past the last number, you'd need to prevent it going less than 1.

Comment: I see what ur saying. But if I adjust it even to -1 it will then show 0 on the nav bar. if I go even further it will show in the minus.

Comment: this is what i was implying ... you need to do something like  $start = max(0, $start - 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $start = $_REQUEST['page'] ? : 0;
    if ($start % 9 != 0) {
        $start = 9 * floor($start/9);

    }
    $end = min($total, $start+9);

    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        echo "<a href='?page='.$i>".$i."</a>";
    }
```